# Is it possible to sort lines in Vim alphabetically if lines are with Cyrillic text?

Tags: sorting, vim, encoding

I've just tried to process Cyrillic text and found out that `:sort` command orders lines not properly. Actually, this concerns Ukrainian letter like `є`, `і`, `ї` etc. Lines starting with those letters go first for some reason before `а`. Is there a way to order lines correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Using vim's native sort: [no](https://superuser.com/a/474271/245923).

> From VIM 7.3 ':help sort'
>
> > The details about sorting depend on the library function used.  There is no
> >     guarantee that sorting is "stable" or obeys the current locale.  You will have
> >     to try it out.

That said, you can use the GNU coreutils `sort` to accomplish this for you.  It's locale-aware and supports many different locale configurations.  Assuming you have your locale settings configured properly, you should be able to sort the text using `:{range}!sort`.

Comment: That is sad :( I do not want to change system locale etc. I just need sorting rules used in KOI8-U for Ukrainian. Is there a way to configure this from vimrc?

Comment: You can run the external sort from vim with `:%!sort`. This will sort all file contents.